# Why is my 2D array printing incorrectly? (using fprintf)

Tags: c, arrays, printf, 2d

I have a 2D VLA that contains X number of rows and 6 columns.

This SaveInfo function stores values into each column for each row, and the prints the function to a text file.

Everything prints correctly, except for the last "Interest Paid" Column

What could be causing this issue? Could it be where I'm freeing the memory for printArray? It is currently at the bottom of my main function

Here is the array declaration in main:

```
  double **printArray = malloc(arrSize * sizeof *printArray);
  for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
    printArray[i] = malloc(arrSize * sizeof *printArray[i]);
  }
```

```
void SaveInfo(double interestRate, int duration, double principalAmt, double monthlyPayment, double** printArray) {
  double remainingBalance = principalAmt;
  double monthlyPrinciple;
  double totalPaid = 0;
  double interestPaid;
  double monthlyInterest;

  //open file in write mode
  FILE *p;
  p = fopen("outputFile.txt", "w");

  //With every month as a row, assign variable values to column in current row (month)
  for(int i = 0; i < duration * 12; i++) {

    printArray[i][0] = i + 1;

    monthlyInterest = (interestRate/12) * remainingBalance;
    printArray[i][1] = monthlyInterest;

    monthlyPrinciple = monthlyPayment - monthlyInterest;
    printArray[i][2] = monthlyPrinciple;

    remainingBalance = remainingBalance - monthlyPrinciple;
    printArray[i][3] = remainingBalance;

    totalPaid = totalPaid + monthlyPayment;
    printArray[i][4] = totalPaid;

    interestPaid = interestPaid + monthlyInterest;
    printArray[i][5] = interestPaid;

  }

  //Print printArray using nested loop
  fprintf(p, "%-7s %-14s %-14s %-14s %-14s %-14s", "Month", "Interest", "Principal", "Balance", "Total Paid", "Interest Paid");
  fprintf(p, "\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < duration * 12; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      if(j == 0) {
        fprintf(p, "| %-3.0lf | ", printArray[i][j]);
      }
      else {
        fprintf(p, "| %10.2lf | ", printArray[i][j]);
      }
    }
    fprintf(p, "\n");
  }
}
```

```
Month   Interest       Principal      Balance        Total Paid     Interest Paid 
| 1   | |       4.17 | |      81.44 | |     918.56 | |      85.61 | |      -1.#R | 
| 2   | |       3.83 | |      81.78 | |     836.78 | |     171.21 | |      -1.#R | 
| 3   | |       3.49 | |      82.12 | |     754.66 | |     256.82 | |      -1.#R | 
| 4   | |       3.14 | |      82.46 | |     672.20 | |     342.43 | |      -1.#R | 
| 5   | |       2.80 | |      82.81 | |     589.39 | |     428.04 | |      -1.#R | 
| 6   | |       2.46 | |      83.15 | |     506.24 | |     513.64 | |      -1.#R | 
| 7   | |       2.11 | |      83.50 | |     422.74 | |     599.25 | |      -1.#R | 
| 8   | |       1.76 | |      83.85 | |     338.89 | |     684.86 | |      -1.#R | 
| 9   | |       1.41 | |      84.20 | |     254.70 | |     770.47 | |      -1.#R | 
| 10  | |       1.06 | |      84.55 | |     170.15 | |     856.07 | |      -1.#R | 
| 11  | |       0.71 | |      84.90 | |      85.25 | |     941.68 | |      -1.#R | 
| 12  | |       0.36 | |      85.25 | |      -0.00 | |    1027.29 | |      -1.#R |
```

Comment: How was the array declared and initialized prior to calling the function?

Comment: Added the array declaration to my post. There is another function that is the same as SaveInfo that uses printf instead of fprintf. The output from that function works fine.

Comment: `interestPaid` is used uninitialized in `interestPaid = interestPaid + monthlyInterest;`.

Comment: concerning your last edit, please read 
[**How should we treat posts that are vandalized by their original authors?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106812/251777)

Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. 

By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP code uses `interestPaid` uninitialized. With `double interestPaid;`, `interestPaid` is *declared*, but has an *indeterminate* value. Code goes on to attempt to use this indeterminate value (causing undefined behavior) with:

```
interestPaid = interestPaid + monthlyInterest;
```

To fix, initialize with:

```
double interestPaid = 0;
```